# How do I translate WordPress and WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, poedit

I've got a WordPress website with WooCommerce. I need to translate it to another language than English, and, the problem is - most of texts are translated automatically in my language, but, for some reason few of them are still in English language.

For testing purposes, I had downloaded both WooCommerce translation files from another (working) site and nothing changed - only if I change whole theme, site is all in proper language.

What could be important - I'm editing theme by using a child theme.

Where can I find the solution? Maybe I should "force" the translation - but how? I know that theme is messing with that, but I can't change it for another...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing you can do is use a plugin like [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/). The theme might be missing translations or worse, directly written thus not allowing you to translate. If you feel up for it, try [Poedit](https://poedit.net/)

Comment: That's not the solution...

Translating files (like .pot etc) are saved and translated well. The problem is, that even if I've got these files saved, theme is displaying  SOME english language messages ruthlessly.

Comment: @D_Jedrzejewski That's part of the solution for the information you've provided. We don't know what theme you're using or if those missing translations are missing. [Refer to this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80334/how-to-make-a-wordpress-plugin-translation-ready) if you'd prefer to check directly in your theme if it's translation ready.